# Get duplicate rows only by certain fields from inner join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, duplicates, inner-join

How do I get duplicates rows only from below query?

```
 SELECT p.CustomerNumber
          ,pn.[Title]
          ,pn.[FirstName]
          ,pn.[LastName]
          ,a.[AgentID]
          ,a.[AgentName]
          ,a.[PersonID]
          ,pe.[EMailAddress]
          ,(SELECT TOP 1 pp.[PhoneCode] FROM [Rez].[PersonPhone] pp WHERE pp.PersonID = p.PersonID ORDER BY pp.ModifiedUTC DESC) AS Phone
      FROM [Rez].[Person] p
      INNER JOIN [Rez].[PersonName] pn ON p.PersonID = pn.PersonID
      INNER JOIN [Rez].[Agent] a ON a.PersonID = p.PersonID
      INNER JOIN [Rez].[PersonEMail] pe ON pe.PersonID = p.PersonID
      INNER JOIN [Rez].[AgentRole] ar ON ar.[AgentID] = a.[AgentID]
      WHERE a.CreatedUTC > '2018-01-01'
      ORDER BY pe.[EMailAddress], pn.[FirstName], pn.[LastName], p.[DOB]
```

In the above query I want to get the duplicate records by pe.[EMailAddress], pn.[FirstName], pn.[LastName], p.[DOB].

Current data:

```
First Name  Last Name   Agent Id    DOB          Email
server      test        2803815     11/28/2002  ab@d.com
server      test        2803815     11/28/2002  ab@d.com
Test        TC          2803882     11/28/2002  cc@testmail.com
Test        AAA         2804713     11/28/2002  aa@sqdev.com
server      test        2803015     11/28/2002  ab@d.com
```

In the above data I want to get only first 2 rows & last row becuase those are same data with same FirstName, LastName,DOB & Email address

Required Data:

```
server      test        2803815     11/28/2002  ab@d.com
server      test        2803815     11/28/2002  ab@d.com
server      test        2803015     11/28/2002  ab@d.com
```

Comment: Please post a sample of what you are seeing and what you want to see.

Comment: If you have two records with the same emailaddress, how do you decide which `AgentId` to show?

Comment: I want to show records with all Agent Id. Records with same pe.[EMailAddress], pn.[FirstName], pn.[LastName], p.[DOB]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Please edit your question and show a sample of data that you are seeing and what you want to see.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. To get the first two rows use `SELECT TOP 2` I am going to edit your question with what I assume you want as output. Please edit if it's not right.

Comment: No, top 2 records are duplicate records with same FirstName, LastName,DOB & Email address.
Thats why I want to get those

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this method to count records in place and exclude those with only one record

```
SELECT * FROM
(

SELECT T1.*, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 
                T1.CustomerNumber,
                T1.Title,
                T1.FirstName,
                T1.[LastName],
                T1.[AgentID],
                T1.[AgentName],
                T1.[PersonID],
                T1.[EMailAddress]
) As DuplicateRowCount

FROM
     (
      SELECT p.CustomerNumber
          ,pn.[Title]
          ,pn.[FirstName]
          ,pn.[LastName]
          ,a.[AgentID]
          ,a.[AgentName]
          ,a.[PersonID]
          ,pe.[EMailAddress]
          ,(SELECT TOP 1 pp.[PhoneCode] FROM [Rez].[PersonPhone] pp 
           WHERE pp.PersonID = p.PersonID ORDER BY pp.ModifiedUTC DESC) AS Phone
           FROM [Rez].[Person] p
           INNER JOIN [Rez].[PersonName] pn ON p.PersonID = pn.PersonID
           INNER JOIN [Rez].[Agent] a ON a.PersonID = p.PersonID
           INNER JOIN [Rez].[PersonEMail] pe ON pe.PersonID = p.PersonID
           INNER JOIN [Rez].[AgentRole] ar ON ar.[AgentID] = a.[AgentID]
           WHERE a.CreatedUTC > '2018-01-01'
     ) T1
) T2
WHERE T2.DuplicateRowCount > 1
ORDER BY T2.[EMailAddress], T2.[FirstName], T2.[LastName], T2.[DOB]
```